# Cannot get the image url in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageurl

I need to get the image URL after I uploaded it to firebase storage. After that, the image URL will be added to my firebase database together with other user data. However, the link keeps perceived as abc, I wonder why it will not be overwritten by the

```
link = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

In the `uploadImage()` method. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnChoose, btnUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri filePath;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private String username;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private String role = "therapist";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String email, psd, link = "abc";
    private UploadTask upload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            username = extras.getString("name");
            email = extras.getString("email");
            psd = extras.getString("psd");
        }


        btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choosedevice);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nexttothome);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadImage();
                Signup();
            }
        });
        compname = findViewById(R.id.compnameregister);
        adr1 = findViewById(R.id.adr1register);
        adr2 = findViewById(R.id.adr2register);


        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void uploadImage() {

        if (filePath != null) {
            final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            ref.putFile(filePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RoleInfo2.this, "Your picture Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        link = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private void Signup() {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, psd).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                try {
                    //check if successful
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(A.this, "Couldn't register, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
        String compname1 = compname.getText().toString().trim();
        String adr11 = adr1.getText().toString().trim();
        String adr21 = adr2.getText().toString().trim();
        // Write new user
        sendToDatabase(user.getUid(), username, role, link, compname1, adr11, adr21);

    }

    private void sendToDatabase(String userId, String username, String role, String link, String compname1, String adr11, String adr21) {
        User thera = new User(username, role, link);
        Company comp = new Company(compname1, adr11, adr21);
        mDatabase.child("user").child(userId).setValue(thera);
        mDatabase.child("company").child(userId).setValue(comp);
    }


}
```

Comment: Because you're not waiting for the upload to be finished and to have the link back before signing up. So when you sign up, the link isn't there yet. Do you realize that all these onComplete listeners are necessary because the tasks are **asynchronous**? I.e. when you call uploadImage(), it doesn't wait until the upload is finished before executing the next line of code. It just starts the upload in the background and immediately goes to the next instruction.

Comment: Android `AsyncTask` will be of great help here.

Comment: Is the Toast appearing?

Comment: @JBNizet there is a calback. so after the image is completely uploaded, the inside method will be executed it is not asynchronous

Comment: @Shantanu If it was synchronous, it would not expect a callback. It would block untile the upload is complete and return the task result. It's even written in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#putFile(android.net.Uri)): *Asynchronously uploads from a content URI to this StorageReference.*. You don't seem to understand what "asynchronous" means.

Comment: @JBNizet My mistake, I used the wrong word. I meant that the callback is registered but it is executed only after the upload is fully complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your **Signup()** method fired before the asynchronous task running in uploadImage(). Try to put Signup() into **onComplete()** in uploadImage().

Such like,

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(RoleInfo2.this, "Your picture Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            link=task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

            Signup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). but is it the way I get the image URL seems wrong? because i get this "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@e25bfbf" save in my database

Comment: At current version of Firebase api you need get download uri by using StorageRefence, like Uri uri = storage.getReference().getDownloadUrl().getResult();